# VB.Net DLL Event, C# Handler

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I have a VB.NET dll (written by someone else) and I require that it publishes and raises an event that will (typically) be handled by C#.

If the DLL were C# then this would be simple,

```
(client)
myDLL.OnClick += doClick

(Dll)
if (OnClick != null) OnClick(....

i.e. 2 lines of code
```

but perhaps it's my frustration at VB.NET, but I cannot find a simple example of how to do this.

Can someone please show/explain how to define and raise an event in VB.NET, that can be handled within C#?

Thanks

MM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested this and its exactly the same as it normally is - raise the event in VB.Net (as you normally would)

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Event TestEvent()

    Public Sub RaiseTestEvent()
        RaiseEvent TestEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then reference the VB.Net assembly and consume the event in C# (again, as you normally would)

```
var class1 = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
class1.TestEvent += () => Console.WriteLine("Test Event");
class1.RaiseTestEvent();
```

See [Raising Events and Responding to Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

VB Uses the `Event` keyword.

```
Public Event SomethingChanged (byval sender as object, e as eventargs)
```

Subscribe to it in C# as you would any other event.